# Process Blocks of Data in a Dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a very simple dataframe an its is like this:

```
id  ts                  val
A   2013-01-01 00:00:00 12
A   2013-01-01 00:00:00 543
B   2013-01-01 00:00:00 76
B   2013-01-01 00:00:00 76
A   2013-01-01 01:00:00 11
C   2013-01-01 01:00:00 42
C   2013-01-01 02:00:00 48
```

What I want to do is to rescale all values, so they can be between 0 and 1, but grouping by id. In other words, I need to calculate min's and max's for each block of id and then rescale each row by taking its value, subtract from the min group value and divide by min-max. In R form:

```
function rescale01 <- function(curr, min, max) {return (curr-min/max-min)}
```

I found a way to get min's and max's from this dataframe, but is too cheesy:

```
ddply(df[,c(1,3)], "tag", function(x){
    y <- subset(x, select= -tag)
    c(apply(y, 2, min), apply(y, 2, max))
})
```

Can you suggest a better way to achieve what I need?

Thanks!

Comment: Please allow women to answer your question as well, i.e. avoid "Can you guys" ...

Comment: How should values in groups with only one unique value be scaled?

Comment: @RomainFrancois, you are right. I will edit to remove this foolish sexism.

Comment: @Henrik This will never happen, as data is been preprocessed to remove pitfalls like this.

Comment: @RafaBorges, OK! Then you might pre-process your example data as well (only one value in group C) ;)

Comment: @Henrik Done! Added a new row so people won't get confused. Just for sake of curiosity, the example data is not actually real data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps using `dplyr::mutate`:

```
> df <- data.frame( id = rep( c(1,2), each = 5 ), x = 1:10 )
> group_by(df, id) %>% mutate( x = ( x-min(x) ) / ( max(x) - min(x) ) )
Source: local data frame [10 x 2]
Groups: id

   id    x
1   1 0.00
2   1 0.25
3   1 0.50
4   1 0.75
5   1 1.00
6   2 0.00
7   2 0.25
8   2 0.50
9   2 0.75
10  2 1.00
```

Comment: This seems great! I will update my R (currently I'm using version 3.0.1) and give a try!

Comment: Just to be sure: when you said %>%, did you mean %.% or am I loosing something here?

Comment: Newer versions of `dplyr` use `%>%` from `magrittr` instead of `%.%`, but `%.%` has been kept as an alias (for now).

Comment: Thanks! I have never used dplyr before, but seems that I will fall in love really fast!

Answer (score 1):

The base function `ave()` would also work just fine (using @Romain's sample data)

```
df <- data.frame( id = rep( c(1,2), each = 5 ), x = 1:10 )
df$rescaled <- with(df, ave(x, id, FUN=function(x) {(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))}))
df;
```